# Brave out or brave through a night

Tags: grammar, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrasal-verbs

Let's say you are storytelling a haunted mansion's ghost stories. In the middle of your story you say:

> Many had tried to **brave out** a night in the mansion, but nobody lasted before midnight.(my sentence construction)

Or

> Many had tried to **brave through** a night in the mansion, but nobody lasted before midnight.(excerpt)

From my Google search, I think the **''brave out''** is correct=who endure a difficult/unpleasant situation, and I believe the **''brave through''** is wrongly used by the unknown online writer(I think, but not sure hehe, more likely not a native englishman) Which is really correct?

Comment: I guess you meant "but nobody lasted *until/past* midnight".

Comment: Do ''before midnight'' and ''past midnight'' not the same?

Comment: You have to include "nobody lasted". "Nobody lasted *past* midnight" means everyone dropped out by midnight." In "Nobody lasted *before* midnight", can you say what time (range) it was when the last person dropped out?

Comment: The time range is *before* midnight, so it is before 12mn, is this not clear?

Comment: So when did the last person drop out? Yesterday? The day before? Both are before midnight, right?

Comment: Hmm, about the ''many had tried'' I am saying this as multiple attempts from different days by various kinds of people(in the story:karate black belters, others are fraternity clubs as initiation rites) so its on different days. I can't answer this, unfortunately,  because the article didn't specify the exact time, BUT lets say around 10-11pm, months of Feb., April, Nov.. alright?

Comment: OK, but I still don't think it is the best way to say that. The phrase adds an expectation that something will happen after midnight. For example - "We had a light dinner last night, but nobody ate dessert before midnight." (They probably ate the dessert after midnight.)

Comment: Oh I see, I'm not aware of that time range that it should be ''past midnight'' thx. Anyway, my question is brave through vs. brave out, not this one.